# How to get the predicted intent with confidence using agent rasa sdk chatbot

Tags: python, chatbot, rasa, rasa-sdk

I am loading the trained rasa models manually by using this

```
agent = Agent.load(
                model,
                action_endpoint=EndpointConfig(ACTION_ENDPOINT)
            )
```

And i am predicting the result like this

```
botResponse = await agent.handle_text(query)
```

but this just returns the response as text, but i need the confidence and intent name as well

I tried the `handle_message` but still it does not give confidence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can retrieve this information from the `tracker_store` instance of the `Agent`. To do so, firstly make sure that you pass a sender id while calling `agent.handle_text(query, sender_id="some sender id")`. Then retrieve the tracker with:

```
current_tracker = agent.get_or_create_tracker(sender_id="some sender id")
```

Once you have the tracker, you can retrieve the NLU parsed data of the last sent message with :

```
user_event = tracker.get_last_event_for(UserUttered)
if user_event:
    nlu_parse_data = user_event.parse_data
```

`nlu_parse_data` should look something like this:

```
"text": "Hi MoodBot.",
        "parse_data": {
          "intent": {
            "id": 3068390702409455462,
            "name": "greet",
            "confidence": 0.9968197345733643
          },
          "entities": [],
          "text": "Hi MoodBot.",
          "message_id": "47efa155fc234abea554242883f0a74e",
          "metadata": {},
          "intent_ranking": [
            {
              "id": 3068390702409455462,
              "name": "greet",
              "confidence": 0.9968197345733643
            },
            {
              "id": -7997748339392136471,
              "name": "bot_challenge",
              "confidence": 0.0019184695556759834
            },
            {
              "id": -3856210704443307570,
              "name": "mood_unhappy",
              "confidence": 0.0010514792520552874
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

I used two different apis of rasa to achieve the same

To get the intent and confidence of the query `parse_message_using_nlu_interpreter` and to get the response `handle_text`

```
queryResponseList = await agent.handle_text(query)
intentInfo = await agent.parse_message_using_nlu_interpreter(query)
intent = Intent(**{
            "name": intentInfo["intent"]["name"],
            "confidence": intentInfo["intent"]["confidence"]
        })
```